# I am getting function as undefined while i trigger a bind on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hearing a input, while input is changed i am getting value. as a initial i am passing 1 as a default. so after that the user change the value i should get the values,

But i am getting error as : `undefined is not a function`

what is the issue..?

here is my code :

```
var docLoader = function (params) {

    window.container = window.container || $("#tenderContent");

    return {

        init : function () {
            this.container = container.find("#documentscroll");
            this.inputPage = container.find("#inputpage");
            this.width = this.container.width();
            this.height = this.container.height();
            this.preload();
            this.inputChange();
            $(this.inputPage).bind("change paste keyup", this.inputChange);
        },

        preload : function () {
            var that = this;
            this.container.load("../common/preloader/index.html", 
                function(msg){
                $('#mask').css({width:that.width,height:that.height});
            });
        },

        //load page

        loadPage : function (num) {
            this.container.load("Doc/chapter"+num+"/index.html");
        },

        //input change

        inputChange : function (e) {
            var inputVal = e != undefined ? e.target.value : 1;
            this.loadPage(inputVal); //while page load it works, getting value from input, on change i am getting error.
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    docLoader().init();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        docLoader().init();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function (`inputChange:`) `this` is reference to current `($(this.inputPage)`) element, that why you get error (because in element there is not method `loadPage`). To fix it, you need bind `this` (which is reference to `object` that located in `return {}`) to function, there are several ways how to do it

```
$(this.inputPage).bind("change paste keyup", this.inputChange.bind(this));
```

Or

```
var _this = this;
$(this.inputPage).bind("change paste keyup", function (e) {
   _this.inputChange(e)
});
```

Or

```
$(this.inputPage).bind("change paste keyup", $.proxy(this.inputChange, this));
```

About [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)